# SAP Java Connector

Tags: java, sapjco3

I am trying to develop an application in Java with the SAP Java Connector, but I have problems when I try to execute the jar file that I export from Eclipse.

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo
        at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:56)
        at TABLE_BSAK.TEST(TABLE_BSAK.java:68)
        at TABLE_BSAK.main(TABLE_BSAK.java:551)
Exception in thread "JCoPoolFinalizerThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ConnectionManager.clearAllFactories(ConnectionManager.java:106)
        at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ConnectionManager$PoolFinalizer.run(ConnectionManager.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you researched this issue? Similar questions have been asked on SO many times before. Here is just one of them: [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java).

Comment: Here is another - specifically about the SAP Java Connector: [SAP JCO JAVA Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993401/sap-jco-java-could-not-initialize-class-com-sap-conn-jco-jco).